# How to manipulate data in one column of a dataframe based on data in another column of another dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes as shown below and I need a 3rd DF from these two.

```
    DF1
Name Value 
abc  100
def  200
xyz  500

    DF2
Name Share1 Share2
abc   50%     50%
def   25%     75%
xyz    0      100%

    Resultant DF
Name Share1  Share2
abc   50       50
def   50       150
xyz    0       500
```

How to split the value column in DF1 into 2 columns based on the criteria in Share1 and Share2 columns of DF2 ?

Here the value of abc = 100 in DF1,50% of it should go to share1 and 50% to share2 in the resultant DF. Similarly value of def=200 in DF1, 25% of it should go to share1 and 75% to share2 in resultant DF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two `dataframes` and apply `UDF` for cleaning & calculating the share values:

```
//UDF to remove % from the share columns & calculate the final value

sqlContext.udf().register("valueUDF", (UDF2<String, Integer, Double>) (share, value) -> {
    Double sharePercent = Double.valueOf(share.replace("%", ""))/100;
    return value * sharePercent;
}, DataTypes.DoubleType);

//join two dfs & apply the UDF on the same columns

Dataset<Row> result = df2.join(df1, "Name")
   .withColumn("Share1", callUDF("valueUDF", col("Share1"), col("Value")))
   .withColumn("Share2", callUDF("valueUDF", col("Share2"), col("Value")))
   .drop("Value");

result.show();
```

Output:

```
+----+------+------+
|Name|Share1|Share2|
+----+------+------+
| abc|  50.0|  50.0|
| def|  50.0| 150.0|
| xyz|   0.0| 500.0|
+----+------+------+
```